# Animation on max-height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with a particular height, and when I toggle the "collapsed" class, it's supposed to shrink to a particular max-height if the div was too tall. I've been trying to animate this shrinking, but haven't figured it out. I've looked it up online and it seems like adding the following lines to the element should suffice.

```
-moz-transition: 1s;
-ms-transition: 1s;
-o-transition: 1s;
-webkit-transition: 1s;
transition: 1s;
```

However, it hasn't been working regardless of which classes I assign these to. I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chhu0zfs/) at .

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below, I updated your example.  These are the fixes:

1. You need to add a property to animate in the `transition`. In your case `max-height`.
2. Your `#rect` rule was overriding your `.collapsed` rule because it had a higher specificity.  You can use `#rect.collapsed` instead.
3. You need to set an initial `max-height` and an arbitrary `height` that is greater than or equal to the `max-height` in both states.

I noticed in your example that you could more easily transition the `height` property, but I assume in your actual project you're unable?

```js
$("#toggle").click(function() {
    $("#rect").toggleClass("collapsed");
});
```

```css
#rect {
    background-color:red; 
    max-height: 200px;
    height: 2000px; /* arbitrary value >= max-height */
    -moz-transition: max-height 1s;
    -ms-transition: max-height 1s;
    -o-transition: max-height 1s;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
    transition: max-height 1s;
}
#rect.collapsed {
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rect"></div>
<button id="toggle">hi</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! So for context, in the project the point there are several divs, each with a different height, but adding .collapsed to any of these divs should collapse them to a given max-height (if need be). Basically, I can't think of a way to get around this without keeping max-height at auto. Any ideas for way to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

`transition` only works if the height property you're changing wasn't resolving to `auto`.

I've updated [your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chhu0zfs/1/) to reflect the required changes.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So for context, in the project the point there are several divs, each with a different height, but adding .collapsed to any of these divs should collapse them to a given max-height (if need be). Basically, I can't think of a way to get around this without keeping max-height at auto. Any ideas for way to get around this?

Comment: You can set `max-height` to something absurdly high in the default case. It's a workaround I've done in the past.